# Can you blacklist commands to use via SSH?

Tags: ssh

Does anyone happen to know if there is way to prevent specific commands to be executed via SSH?

For example, lets say that I do not want someone to be able to run `firefox` or `matlab` via SSH, but if they are locally at the machine then it should be fine.

I am mainly asking because I have a piece of software with a license agreement with a no remote use policy.

Comment: You could probably put something together by setting the software group-executable-only, then grant group membership with pam_group (https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_group) when users are logged in locally. Is that the sort of thing you want?

Comment: Not sure if that will 100% work, maybe what i am interested in is limiting some command from /bin to be executable locally...

Comment: @FoxWilson We don't know that this is Linux.

Comment: Also `pam_group` [might not](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=851243) work if users log into gnome desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Variation on [Hunter.S.Thompson's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/393479/116858):

In a shell startup file:

```
if [ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ]; then
   alias matlab='echo "restricted to local users only, sorry"'
   alias firefox='echo "restricted to local users only, sorry"'
fi
```

This does not prevent anyone to bypass these aliases, so instead one could create a shell script for each restricted software.

For example: `/usr/local/bin/matlab`:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ]; then
   echo 'restricted to local users only, sorry' >&2
   exit 1
fi

exec /real/path/to/matlab
```

This does not prevent the user from unsetting their `SSH_CLIENT` environment variable, or executing the real `matlab` program directly.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `~/.bashrc`, this will make sure only a local `tty` will be able to run this sofware.

When the user logins in via `ssh`, server adds an `alias` to the command which will just echo "Restricted. Can only be run locally."

```
whichtty=$( ps hotty $$ | grep pts )

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    alias <software_name>='echo Restricted. Can only be run locally.'
else
    echo 
fi
```

A SSH session will be on a pseudo-terminal slave (`pts`) as shown in the `TTY` column, but not all `pts` connections are `SSH` sessions. For example, programs that create a pseudo-terminal device such as `xterm` or `screen` will show as `pts`. So the downside to this script is that you cannot run this software from your local `xterm` or `screen`.

You will have to run the software from the launcher.